# Compile PHP extension on 64bit debian to 32bit PHP installation

Tags: php, php-extension

I am trying to compile a PHP extension for a 32 bit PHP installation on a 64 bit system. However, I get the following warning when restart apache:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/spotify.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/spotify.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
```

I compile everything using this command:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/phpize; CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 CCASFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --enable-spotify --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config; make && make install
```

The flags should make sure it compiles to 32bit. I have `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib` installed

When it is done compiling (this this log: http://pastebin.com/MqgGgyzv) i do the following command:

```
file /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/spotify.so
```

and it returns

```
/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/spotify.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

So it is clearly not compiling it correctly, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try this solution. It works for me. > How to install PECL PHP extension on 64bit linux while you are using 32bit XAMPP http://montenasoft.com/en/blog/how-install-pecl-php-extension-64bit-linux-while-you-are-using-32bit-xampp

Answer (score 2):

You're *compiling* OK, but the *linker* is inadvertantly creating a 64-bit .so.

The solution is to include "-m32" in your LDFLAGS, too:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/85978/building-a-32-bit-app-in-64-bit-ubuntu

Comment: Tried with this `/opt/lampp/bin/phpize; CXXFLAGS=-m32 CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 CCASFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --enable-spotify --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config; make && make install` but I am still getting the wrong file type.

This is the log returned now: http://pastebin.com/UKshaH27